# converting listbox to my format

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, listbox

I am trying to format the listbox output to conform to my formatter.  It just lists them. Any Ideas?

```
Private Sub Formatter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Formatter.Click
    Dim formatter As String = CStr("{0,-7} {1,6:C2} {3,5}")
    Dim name As String
    name = (First.Text) + (Second.Text)
    Dim x, y As Integer
    x = ((InputBox("Enter a Number")))
    y = (InputBox("Enter another Number"))
    With Values.Items
        .Add(x)
        .Add(y)
        .Add(name)
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `String.Format` to format the values and concatenate them into a single string.  Then you can call `ListBox.Items.Add` just once per item.  Like this:

```
Values.Add(String.Format(formatter, name, x, y))
```

I'm not sure of the order in which you intended to output those values, so that's just an example.